# wp7 NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable() two namespace?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

```
System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();
Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();
```

Is there a difference between?
How to using NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface` inherits from `System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface` and adds the `GetNetworkInterface` static method and the `NetworkInterfaceType` static property. Otherwise, the two classes are identical.

You can find a sample using the `NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable` method on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getisnetworkavailable(v=vs.95).aspx

```
 if (NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
 {
     // Online
 }
 else  
 {
     // Offline
 }
```